# Map User input in Scala, is there any good way for taking user input for Map Elements?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to take String key and Boolean values from user, by below method, is there any better way of doing it?

```scala
val sc = new Scanner(System.in)

println("Please enter First User Name and Boolean value")

val sc1:String  = sc.next();
val sc2:Boolean = sc.nextBoolean()

println("Please enter Second User Name and Boolean value")

val sc3:String  = sc.next();
val sc4:Boolean = sc.nextBoolean()

println("Please enter Third User Name and Boolean value")

val sc5:String  = sc.next();
val sc6:Boolean = sc.nextBoolean()

val map:Map[String,Boolean] = Map(sc1->sc2,sc3->sc4,sc5->sc6)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
    println("Please enter names and values separated by `=`, each pair on its own line. Press ^D when done.")
    val map = Source
       .fromInputStream(System.in)
       .getLines
       .map(_.split("="))
       .map { case Array(a,b) => a -> b.toBoolean }
       .toMap
```